# My form code is not giving the result that I want?

Tags: php, forms

```
<h2>Nepal Form</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
 Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
 <spanc class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
<br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) &&  $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" ?php if (isset($gender) &&  $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

Hello Guys, I was make a PHP Form and I found error on this form coding and I wonder what is it. I have searched serval time, but couldn't figure it out! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: there isn't enough code here, plus you've a syntax error here `?php if`, that's if that's your actual code.

Comment: why this question received an upvote is beyond me; typos.

Comment: Consider using a template engine like Smarty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) &&
```

In 17th Line you have not given "<" to php change as above.

```
<span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
```

And In 11th Line you have given spanc change it as above.

I hope this works for you!!